# Magento user product visit history

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7

Is magento store, user product visit history? 
If yes then how can I fetch it or
if no then how can I do it?

Any web link or resource would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer using the `catalog_product_load_after` event:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <yournamespace_yourmodulename>
                    <type>model</type> 
                    <class>yournamespace_yourmodulename/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductVisitHistory</method>
                </yournamespace_yourmodulename>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_load_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

And in the observer get the data which you need and save it somewhere:

```
public function saveProductVisitHistory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        Mage::log('Customer ID: '.$customer->getId(), null, 'custom.log');

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        Mage::log('Visited Product ID: '.$product->getId(), null, 'custom.log');
    }
}
```